# Adobe Acrobat : html to pdf broken layout

Tags: pdf, html, adobe-acrobat

I recently converted an HTML page to an A4 PDF using Adobe Acrobat Pro. The problem is that layout is not split correctly. Is there a way to edit it (insert some blank space) to push all the broken elements together on one page?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that nobody knows the answer to this problem.

This is the reponse i got using adobe help forums.

> I wouldn't say that's incorrect, just unwanted. HTML isn't paginated
>   and PDF is, by definition. There doesn't seem to be a way to force
>   page breaks, which is a pity.

**How i "solved" the problem?**

I put some extra `<div style="margin-bottom:?;">` elements into the `html`, forcing the fake page breaks. But it is a time consuming solution since you dont really know how many free space you need to create, before previewing it as a4.

Comment: I'm not sure if Adobe Acrobat Pro supports this, but did you look at using the [`page-break-before`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/page-break-before) property?

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Google Chrome browser, you can print the page and save it as PDF file.
The layout will be well preserved.